# zod validation in javaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, zod

```
export type ResetPassword = {
  password: string
  confirmPassword: string
}

export const resetPasswordSchema: ZodType<ResetPassword> = z.object({
  password: z.string().refine((value) => value !== '', {
    message: 'Password is required'
  }),
  confirmPassword: z.string().refine((value) => value !== '', {
    message: 'Password is required'
  }).refine((data) => data.password === data.confirmPassword, {
    message: "Passwords don't match",
    path: ["confirmPassword"], // path of error
  })
})
```

i'm trying to use zod validation to check if the confirm password matches the password and i got this error!

> Property 'password' does not exist on type 'string'.
> Property 'confirmPassword' does not exist on type 'string'.

in this line

```
  }).refine((data) => data.password === data.confirmPassword, {
```

.....................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to put the `refine` method on the end of the schema to get access to all the properties like this:

```
export const resetPasswordSchema: ZodType<ResetPassword> = z.object({
  password: z.string().refine((value) => value !== '', {
    message: 'Password is required'
  }),
  confirmPassword: z.string().refine((value) => value !== '', {
    message: 'Password is required'
  })
})
.refine((data) => data.password === data.confirmPassword, {
    message: "Passwords don't match",
    path: ["confirmPassword"], // path of error
})
```